# A engine de Stackoverflow é Open Source?

Tags: debate

A engine de Stackoverflow é Open Source? vendo as proporções que tem a rede imagino que esta de ser bem complexa e julgo que seria uma boa fonte de estudos.

Comment: Infelizmente, não (muito embora [existam vários clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/37953/177950)).